# Project tango: How implement personalized connection screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I want to implement a personalized connection screen, I'm using the unity SDK. I know when to set it ON but I have no idea when to set it back OFF when the device is steady.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when the API receives the first valid pose indicates that the connection of Tango is finished, and everything works fine.